# Webview progressBar not hiding after page load

Tags: android, webview

I am new with Android developement and I am trying to hide a `ProgressBar` after page not but it is not hiding.

Here is my code for `main_activity.xml` and `MainActivity.java`

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout  
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <WebView
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="715dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">
  </WebView>

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout >
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package test.com.webview;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


WebView webview;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("www.google.com");
}
public  class myWebClient extends WebViewClient{

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // to hide
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }



    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //to show
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // to hide
    }

   }
}
```

I am using onPageStarted and onPageFinished method for progressbar and tried to get some solution from google but nothing seems working or basically it might be because of my experience with android i am not able to make it work so please help me with my code. Thanks

Comment: You're just setting the base WebViewClient in `setWebViewClient()`. You should be setting your custom version.

Comment: @TheWanderer please let me know what changes I should make with my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this line:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

to the next line:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient())
```

Because you are using default client and not your own that you have created.